# How to manage UIAlertViewDelegate when the controller has been discarded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a UIViewController  which starts a UIAlertView
something like

```
- (void) aMethod
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error title"
                                                    message:@"Error message"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show]
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex
{
    NSLOG(@"never called");
}
```

the controller implement the delegate, but right after the alert view call I have a popToRoot,
when I executre this, it shows the alertview as expected and go back to root, as expected but (as expected I guess) the delegate is not called.

How should I do? I guess I'm not doing the right thing

Comment: Are you want to display alert in current page or next page? Or do yo want to go back on alert action?

Comment: you can assign your Appdelegate in delegate property so you can access UIAlertViewdelegate in appdel class

Comment: set delegate of UIAlertView to self.navigationController.viewControllers[0]. And implement alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: delegate method in that view controller

Comment: No one seems to have noticed that in the code shared the `UIAlertView` will never actually be shown. The reason being is that there is no `[alert show];` being called. Is this a typo?

Comment: @caglar is right, but the better design is to present the alert in the root vc's viewDidAppear.  It should detect whatever condition caused this vc to raise the alert.  ... and yeah, it should invoke show.

Comment: @Popeye it is a typo, sorry.

Comment: @vivek the flow works as I want (show an alert while in the background the controller pops out)

Comment: @Bhumit I don't want to mess up with my app delegate (and from that point I won't be able to present view and will be lost)

Comment: Do you actually need to do something when the user taps the OK button on the alert view? If it's just a message and you don't need to do anything specific when the user dismisses the alert, simply pass `nil` as the delegate.

Comment: @rmaddy sure I do :)

Comment: Then you need to change what you are doing. You obviously can't use `self` as the delegate since `self` goes away as soon as you show the alert. Either show the alert from somewhere else or pass another, still existing, object as the delegate. Or don't dismiss the view controller until the alert button is processed.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you, at the end it's what I did, but the question could be how is the right way to do that? Because in that delegate I am presenting a new controller so I need a "parent" controller instance to do so, and since the delegate is not on a UIController I'm stuck again (Of course it could be but not in a elegant way)